# SwiftUI Error: Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I know questions involving this error have been asked before, but I checked them and they haven't been to fix my problem.

I have dictionary called **data** which contains **event**  objects. I am comparing the rowData against all the events in data to see if any of them match. When my search is finished, I don't want to create or update a view, I just want to update a data field.

```
struct addToMyMoves {
    var rowData: row
    //rowData is passed into the struct from an outside View

    func addToMoves() {
        ForEach(data){ event in
            //Error: Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate

                if (event.name == rowData.name)  {
                        event.favorite.toggle()


            }

        }

    }
}
```

When I try to put the the if statement inside a Group {} as suggested in similar posts, as shown below, I get the "Generic parameter 'Content' could not be inferred" error

```
struct addToMyMoves {
    var rowData: row
    //rowData is passed into the struct from an outside View

    func addToMoves() {
        ForEach(data){ event in
            //Error: Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate
            Group {
                if (event.name == rowData.name)  {
                        event.favorite.toggle()

                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ForEach` is not new iteration statement, it is SwiftUI view builder over sequence data. In your case you need old-good `for` statement:

```
   for event in data {
            if (event.name == rowData.name)  {
                    event.favorite.toggle()
        }
    }
```